# Unable to stop GCP VM instance, automatically starts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I've recently taken over a GCP project, created snapshots to restore in case of mistakes, and now I need to restore one of them.

Part of the process includes stopping the currently-running VM instance.

Whenever I do this, the instance automatically starts back up immediately. In the notifications panel, there is only "Stop VM instance "...."", with no errors or the re-starting reported.

I know this doesn't happen with regular VMs, so the previous owner must have done something to automatically start it back up if it goes down.

Does anyone know where I should go looking to safely disable that feature for a while? Or if there's a way to force it to stop for a bit longer?

Comment: Beware that the instance is not necessarily starting back up immediately.  Rather, it may be that a *new instance* is being created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instance is probably being managed. Go to the Google Cloud Console:

- Go to Compute Engine -> Instance Groups. Is this instance listed here?
- Go to Kubernetes Engine. Do you have a cluster running? Is this instance part of a cluster?
- Go to Cloud Functions. Look at each function. Are any of the functions watching or monitoring VM instances?
- Go to Load Balancers -> Backend instances. Check here also.

If your instance is part of an Instance Group, Kubernetes cluster, load balancer back-end, etc. than you do not manage the instance yourself. It is being managed for you. If you shutdown or delete an instance it will be recreated (depending on configuration).

For most of these types of services, the VM instances are stateless, which means that they are recreated from an image, container, etc. Creating snapshots won't help you in this case. Figure out first how your systems are configured before trying to manage them.